# Are the words “proverb” and “pronoun” etymologically related?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I’m not aware of any verb equivalents of a pronoun. We have to say “he did what?”  We don’t just have a single word like we do for nouns that replaces the verb. But do proverbs function on this way at all?  Is there some ancient etymological relationship between pronouns and proverbs?

Comment: Are you talking about proverb meaning "pithy saying", or "pro-verb" meaning a generic word that stands for a verb (as described in @Laurel's answer)?

Comment: Have you checked in say the Online Etymological Dictionary or an encyclopaedia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both words were first used in Middle English. [Pronoun](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED34909) is a word that was created in English but modeled after its counterparts in Latin (pronomen) and French (pronom), using the prefix [pro-](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED34736). [Proverb](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED35054) comes directly from Latin and French, the same sources that got us [verb](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED50932). Ultimately "[pro](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro)" in both words comes from the same root. There are a lot of other words that are related in the same way: problem, provincial, procession, provide, etc.

English does have "pro-verbs", a term formed only in the 19th century as the verb counterpart to pronoun. We use a pro-verb in sentences like "I make pasta just like you do", where "do" means "make pasta". The hypernym that includes both terms and others is [pro-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form). See also [Pro-Verb: The Complement to the Pronoun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-is-a-pro-verb-definition-how-to-use).

Comment: It should probably be noted that the origin of "verb" is Latin "verbum", which just meant "word", not specifically action words. This is where we get words like "verbally" and "verbiage".